# Object.keys equivalent lodash method

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am new to loadash, I am trying to learn good ways to manipulate java script object.

Is there a equivalent loadash method for :

```
Object.keys({ "tab1": "1" , tab2: "2"})[0];
Object.keys({ "tab1": "1" , tab2: "2"})[2];
```

to get list values?

And also if there are easy and good ways to use lodash and any articles that I can go through.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

[`_.keys`](https://lodash.com/docs#keys) should do the trick.

> `_.keys(object)`
>
> Creates an array of the own enumerable property names of `object`.

### Example:

```js
console.log(_.keys({ "tab1": "1" , tab2: "2"}));
console.log(Object.keys({ "tab1": "1" , tab2: "2"}));

// Outputs:
// ["tab1", "tab2"]
// ["tab1", "tab2"]
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.5.1/lodash.js"></script>
```

### Side-note:

Remember that the keys of an object are not necessarily ordered, and so they can come back in any order the host chooses.

Comment: how would i use index to fetch the key

Comment: @user2936008 What do you mean? It returns an array, so you can access the keys using standard array indexes.

Comment: ohh got it so you are basically saying use _.keys({ "tab1": "1" , tab2: "2"})[0] ??

Comment: @user2936008 Yes, but watch out, the keys can come back in any order. The order of the keys is not guaranteed.

Comment: So how to make sure they come in the right order ,what if logic is based on  order.

Comment: @user2936008 If your logic is based on order, you should probably be using an array, perhaps an array of objects.

Comment: But Object.keys always give correct order (Am I assuming since I was testing it 100 times today) is it worth it to use _.keys()

Comment: @user2936008 A given JavaScript host will probably give a consistent output, but that output is not mandated by a specification, so other hosts may use a different order or choose to change that order at any given time. I know Firefox and Chrome used to give different orders at least.

Comment: ohh ok, May be that is the case (I was testing in Chrome) . But Thanks for the answer . And if you have any website which has clean explanation about how to work over JSON object using Lodash, It will be of great help.

Comment: How will you get list of keys with nested keys also? Something list `{id:1, address:{country:'anycountry'}}` which gives `['id', 'address.country']`

Comment: @leopragi You would need to recurse/iterate into the file objects. I don't know of any good libraries for doing that but it wouldn't be to hard to write manually.