# Javascript lodash - data massaging based on attribute value

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I have an array of objects, such as this:

```
var elements = [
{
    LabCode: 'VA',
    Zscore: 0.5,
    Standard: 'std1' 
},

{
    LabCode: 'RE',
    Zscore: 0.53,
    Standard: 'std1' 
},
{
    LabCode: 'VO',
    Zscore: 1.5,
    Standard: 'std1' 
},
{
    LabCode: 'VA',
    Zscore: 3.4,
    Standard: 'std2' 
},
{
    LabCode: 'RE',
    Zscore: 2.45,
    Standard: 'std2' 
},
{
    LabCode: 'VO',
    Zscore: 1.67,
    Standard: 'std2' 
}
]
```

What I need is this:

```
var result = [
{
Standard: 'std1',
VA: 0.5,
RE: 0.53,
VO: 1.5
},

{
Standard: 'std2',
VA: 3.4,
RE: 2.45,
VO: 1.67
}
]
```

Labcodes are dynamic so I need to be able  to dynamically creates the resulted object. I can have many standards and they are also dynamic.

I am using lodash.

**Please note that the property name needs to reflect the fact that labcodes are dynamic as well. This was not addressed in the answer you notes as duplicate.**

Comment: And (with a rep of 10K) you've tried....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can do it simply with *`reduce()`* like this**

```js
var elements = [
                {LabCode: 'VA',Zscore: 0.5, Standard: 'std1' },
                {LabCode: 'RE',Zscore: 0.53,Standard: 'std1' },
                {LabCode: 'VO',Zscore: 1.5, Standard: 'std1' },
                {LabCode: 'VA',Zscore: 3.4, Standard: 'std2' },
                {LabCode: 'RE',Zscore: 2.45,Standard: 'std2' },
                {LabCode: 'VO',Zscore: 1.67,Standard: 'std2' }
               ]

let final = Object.values(elements.reduce((op,cur)=>{
  if( op[cur['Standard']] ) {
    op[cur['Standard']][cur['LabCode']] = cur['Zscore']
  } else {
    op[cur['Standard']] = {
     'Standard' : cur['Standard'],
     [cur['LabCode']]: cur['Zscore']
    }
  }
  return op;
}, {} ))

console.log(final);
```

**Well in case of IE you can use this.**

```js
var elements = [
                    {LabCode: 'VA',Zscore: 0.5, Standard: 'std1' },
                    {LabCode: 'RE',Zscore: 0.53,Standard: 'std1' },
                    {LabCode: 'VO',Zscore: 1.5, Standard: 'std1' },
                    {LabCode: 'VA',Zscore: 3.4, Standard: 'std2' },
                    {LabCode: 'RE',Zscore: 2.45,Standard: 'std2' },
                    {LabCode: 'VO',Zscore: 1.67,Standard: 'std2' }
                   ]

    let final = elements.reduce((op,cur)=>{
      if( op[cur['Standard']] ) {
        op[cur['Standard']][cur['LabCode']] = cur['Zscore']
      } else {
        op[cur['Standard']] = {
         'Standard' : cur['Standard'],
         [cur['LabCode']]: cur['Zscore']
        }
      }
      return op;
    }, {} )
let finalop = [];
for(let key in final){
  finalop.push(final[key])
}
    console.log(finalop);
```

Comment: I don't think this answer makes use of Lodash.

Comment: @sarsnake this is using just normal js. you don't need any loadash for this solution. check the demo

Comment: @sarsnake you can read up here about object keys alternate in loadash https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35566472/object-keys-equivalent-lodash-method

Comment: Sorry. Object.values is not supported in IE https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42830257/alternative-version-for-object-values

Comment: @sarsnake you should mention such things in question itself. anyways added a version for IE also.

Comment: @code maniac Yeah sorry I should have - I just assume that IE needs to be supported since so many people use it. By the way arrow syntax is not supported in IE either.....

Comment: @sarsnake you can trans-pile it using https://babeljs.io/

Answer (score 0):

You can get this done via one `Array.reduce` and some ES6 (without lodash):

```js
var data = [{ LabCode: 'VA', Zscore: 0.5, Standard: 'std1' }, { LabCode: 'RE', Zscore: 0.53, Standard: 'std1' }, { LabCode: 'VO', Zscore: 1.5, Standard: 'std1' }, { LabCode: 'VA', Zscore: 3.4, Standard: 'std2' }, { LabCode: 'RE', Zscore: 2.45, Standard: 'std2' }, { LabCode: 'VO', Zscore: 1.67, Standard: 'std2' } ] 

const result = data.reduce((r, {LabCode, Zscore, Standard}, i, a) => {
  r[Standard] = r[Standard] || {}
  r[Standard][LabCode] = Zscore
  return i == a.length-1 ? Object.keys(r).map(k => ({Standard: k, ...r[k]})) : r
}, {})

console.log(result)
```